# Different ways to get text automatically from Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

Since I'm using scanner, after scanning the barcode into edittext I need to get text from the edittext automatically and check the record for that barcode from the local database.

I know that there is `addTextChangedListener` for getting the text from the edittext automatically. But there are issues with that like it is checking each character of barcode when scanned instead of checking the barcode string in the local database.

Comment: Can't you just use `editText.getText().toString()` whenever you need to get the text?

Comment: I need text after scanning the barcode. Where should I place it exactly?

Comment: I won't be able to answer that - I don't know how you want your app to work, and how the barcode code functions in your app, so I would just say to use if after the barcode has been scanned, as you mentioned. You may need to look at the documentation for the barcode API you are using.

Comment: Where is the text from? Isn't it set by you somewhere?

Comment: Hey @Seenu69 if you solved this, post answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and its methods
  *postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)* and
  *removeCallbacks(Runnable r)*.

In your [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) invoke *removeCallbacks(...)* in order to remove any previous [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and invoke *postDelayed(...)* with a little delay and a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) that will check the barcode string.
So you may accomplish your search in the database in several milliseconds after the last digit was sent to your *EditText*.

Also your scanner may send a special symbol at the end of a barcode. So read its documentation. Probably you don't need [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Handler.html), but you need to wait for that special symbol

Comment: Your answer is looking useful to me. Can you show the answer with some sample code for what you have wrote above?

Comment: I haven't written that code before, so I must  write and debug it from the start. Unfortunately I'm a bit busy now, so I can't do it right now.

Comment: Please do it. I'll approve your answer.